# Ajax Redirect on new page and after display success message

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery-validate

I am working with ajax and php. I want to display message on another page after user successfully added using Ajax. I have tried so much. It's working when first display "Success" message on popup and afrer redirect on another page. But i want to first redirect on another page and after display message.

**User Add Page:**

```
<form action="<?php echo $action_link; ?>" method="post" id="form_user_profile" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="novalidate">

   <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

   <div class="form-body">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label col-md-3">First Name
         <span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
       </label>
       <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="input-icon right">
           <i class="fa"></i>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="<?php echo $user_db[0]['fname']; ?>"> 
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-actions">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
           <input type="submit" class="btn green" name="submit" value="<?php echo $addupdate_msg; ?>">
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

**Ajax in Validate**

```
$("#form_user_profile").validate({
        rules: {
            fname: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            fname: "Please enter first name"
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                url: form.action,
                type: form.method,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    if(response == 1){
                        bootbox.alert("User has been added successfully.", function() {
                            window.location.href= "<?php echo $user_list; ?>";
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
});
```

**Action**

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && $_REQUEST['submit'] == "Add") {

    $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($obj->CONN, $_REQUEST['fname']);    

    $user->setfname($fname);
    $insert = $user->insert();

    ob_get_clean();

    if($insert){
        echo '1';
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "New user has been added successfully.";
    }else{
        echo '0';
    }

    exit;
}
```

Comment: give single quotes to 1 if(response == '1'){ }

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference because he's using loose `==` comparison.

Comment: @jothi it's not working like  if(response == '1'){ }. Actually i want to display success message on another page. Using this, redirect on another page, it's okie. But not display any success message.

Comment: @NeelThakkar; you want to display $_SESSION['msg'] in page another_page.php? have you start the session on the top of page action ?

Comment: @bfahmi Yes, i have start session on this page.

Comment: @NeelThakkar; if you put print($_SESSION['msg']); in another_page.php, what you got ?

Comment: @bfahmi Blank session. Not getting anything.

Comment: @NeelThakkar, ithink it's problem with session, put in your if($insert){ $_SESSION[''msg]= "just test"; echo $_SESSION[''msg];  }. and in ajax, success: function(response) { alert(esponse); ... } what you got ?

Comment: @bfahmi Once more i'll check whole process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117480/discussion-between-neel-thakkar-and-bfahmi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The success popup appears before the user is redirected because of the following code:

```
if(response == 1){
    bootbox.alert("User has been added successfully.", function() {
        window.location.href= "<?php echo $user_list; ?>";
    });
}
```

If you wish to show a message on the new page instead, just redirect the user

```
if(response == 1)window.location.href= "<?php echo $user_list; ?>";
```

On **the new page** where you send the customer after success, show the message with something like

```
$(function() {
    bootbox.alert(<?= $_SESSION['msg'] ?>);
});
```

Comment: I have set session on another page, but still not display any success message from session.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if there is a `$_SESSION['msg']` set on the page you are directing it to, if set then `alert`.

Jquery:

```
if(response == 1){window.location.href= "<?php echo $user_list ?>";}
```

Then, `$user_list` page:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
  echo '$(document).ready(function(){
            bootbox.alert('.$_SESSION['msg'].');
        })';
}
```

Note, I'm using the single quotes so that PHP doesn't think `$` is a variable.